# Debugging executables across git commits

Tags: c++, git, debugging, gdb

Has anyone come up with a good solution for debugging executables between different code versions using git? Basically, I want to be able to generate side-by-side executables between my recent set of commits and an older set of commits, as well as keep track of the relevant code to go with it, without everything overwriting when jumping between the commits.

Currently my method of doing this is to make/compile the current code and rename the executable and whatever code I'm trying to analyze in debugger (gdb in my case). Now, to the old code, I like to checkout a new branch before checking out the older commit because I'm paranoid and it builds the reflog for extra safety and check-pointing (I know it's not really necessary). I checkout old code and run the make file on the older commit. Now I have my side-by-side executables that I can run with gdb. It's all a bit tedious though, especially if a few headers/files have changed (I like to break up my code) and also if I now want to make changes and recompile (I've got tons of references/includes and I basically just have to start the process over again). Anyone have a better method?

Comment: I have two or three copies of most or the repos I work with on a daily basis.

Comment: It seems that multiple worktrees is still in development progress, so I guess if you have many states then, like you say, you just have to have multiple repos going. Disk space is getting cheaper :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem when trying to debug/upgrade a library which needed to be properly installed on the system (using *make install*) and make jumps between last stable and development versions.

Since version 2.6.0 (about three years from now), you now can use

```
git worktree
```

It basicaly enables yourself to turn any directory, at any place, into an annex of an official git local repository. It does by filling a `.git` textfile (instead of the regular subdirectory) at its top level, containing informations that point the original one. On the repository side, this annex is declared as so and a new branch is created.

Consequently, you now have the possibility to perform `git checkout` onto two different revisions simultaneously (one per working directory). And you may add as many annexes as you need. When you're done, simply delete all useless annexes, then call `git worktree prune` to make it dismiss everything that no longer exists (you may use `git worktree lock` to prevent some of them to be deleted if their annex directory is to be unavailable sometimes, with removable devices for instance). This will let you compile two different versions of the same application at the same time.

If, however, you need to retrieve a particular revision of your soft but you can't tell which one before you have compiled it, you may want to use

```
git bisect run
```

…instead, which will automatically call a script that tells if a revision is good or bad. It's useful when a compilation is rather long and when the whole search can span over several days.

Here's a link to the [documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree/2.17.0) related to *git worktree*.

Comment: Nice, this looks just like what I need! I'll have to give it a go tomorrow.