# Copy Git index into a temp folder

Tags: git, git-checkout

Suppose I have a utility `some-check {baseline_folder} {working_folder}` which does some comparison on sets of files (not the individual files).

I'd like to use this utility in two slightly different use cases:

- validation of working tree against the HEAD revision;
- pre-commit validation of index vs. HEAD

The first use case is pretty straightforward, since getting the baseline (i.e. HEAD) into a temp folder is not a big deal.

The real question is how to get index into some folder. The only way I see is something like:

1. create a stash
2. apply it back immediately
3. use `git-archive` to create a zip by the stash ref
4. unzip it to a temp folder
5. drop the stash

Is there any less verbose way to do it?

UPD: Long story short: the problem is how to get a folder which has HEAD+stage, but without modified/untracked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For validating what's in the index, you can extract everything that is in it to a temporary work-tree this way:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)                # or your other chosen method
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" 0 1 2 3 15   # do something different in other languages

GIT_WORK_TREE=$tmpdir git checkout-index --all
```

Be sure that the temporary directory exists and is empty (the `mktemp -d` here does that), and be sure to clean up when done (the `trap` here does that).

Note that attribute rules will be applied to the `git checkout-index` step.  Using `git archive`, you gain more control with `export-ignore` and `export-subst`.  If you want to use that method, you can turn the current index into a tree object using `git write-tree`, and then use `git archive` on that tree object.

Note also that the `git write-tree` method raises an error with an unmerged index, while the `git checkout-index` method simply omits the unmerged files from the target work-tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew about the GIT_WORK_TREE trick, but never heard of `git checkout-index`

Comment: Regular `git checkout` can also extract from the index, but does not have `--all`, `--stage`, and some of the other little plumbing-type tricks that `git checkout-index` provides.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any less verbose way to do it?

There is better :

```
git worktree
```

This allows you to turn any directory into a annex of a git repository, enabling you to check out two different revision simultaneously. And you can add as many annexes as you need, then discard them when no longer required. It's very useful, for example, to work on two versions of a same library (for instance, its last stable version and the tip of the development one).

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401520/debugging-executables-across-git-commits/50401736#50401736) here. This should match your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. I certainly use `git worktree` to get HEAD into temp folder. But it does not help me to get staged files from current tree.

Comment: Each work-tree has its own index, so this is more of a hassle than it seems.